# Styling a form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have the following form:

```
  = form_tag '/posts', {id: "link-form"} do
    = text_field :post, :link
    = submit_tag "Add link", {id: "submit-button"}
```

, which renders:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/posts" id="link-form" method="post">
    <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
        <input id="post_link" name="post[link]" type="text">
         <input id="submit-button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Add link">
 </form>
```

It seems that Rails automatically add another div in the second line:
`<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">`

This div inherits everything from its parents, and I can't get access to this div (such as assigning an ID) to change its appearance.

How I can access this div, or how to go around it?

Comment: What happened to the closing tag for the div?

Comment: I actually removed the hidden input and accidentally removed the closing tag too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its div for hidden inputs with existing data. 
You do not have to touch it.